# Не запускаются .py файлы в ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Не могу запустить .py файл. Установил python 3.6.6 на Ubuntu, установил matplotlib через команду:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

Если ввожу команду "pip3 list", то выводит что все установлено.
Однако, когда я пытаюсь запустить файл через команды:

```
python3 myfile.py
```

или

```
sh myfile.py
```

или через pycharm, то всегда выдает что мол данной библиотеки нет на компьютере.

Comment: Добавить ``python3`` в переменную PATH.

Comment: выполнил ваши указания:
linuxuser@VBU:~$ PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
далее ввел:
linuxuser@VBU:~$ python3 myfile.py
выдало(если вкратце):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал пользоваться virtualenv:

```
mkdir -p prjct1
virtualenv-3 prjct1
cd prjct1
source bin/activate
pip install matplotlib
vim myfile.py
python myfile.py
```

В этом случае проблем с доступом к установленным дополнениям внутри этого окружения не будет.

Закончить работу в текущем окружении:

```
deactivate
```

В моем примере, окружение будет создано для python3 (должен быть установлен в системе). pip так же будет pip3.

Comment: Спасибо большое!Я пробовал через виртуальное окружение, но тоже выдает ошибку. Попробовал Ваш способ, но мне не дает установить установить "vim".Ругается

Comment: vim это просто для примера, можно использовать любой, вам удобный, редактор.
Покажите какую ошибку "выдает" при использовании виртуального окружения.

Comment: спасибо большое!я попробую

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что на самом деле, всё просто. В убунте по умолчанию, ставится питон-2. И все приложения (Cherry например) написаны на втором питоне.  После того, как Вы установили третий питон, наверное сдели его дефаультовым.

В питон-приложениях, которые уже были установлены, в первой строке (#!) версия питона явно не указана. Поэтому программы, написаные для второго питона система запускает с интерпретатором третьего. Поскольку языки довольно сильно различаются, то возникают ошибки и приложение завершается.

Для борьбы с этим явлением я просто **явно** прописал в первой строки приложений для второго питона *#/ /usr/bin/python2* и всё заработало.

Теперь по поводу библиотек (модулей). Они тоже **разные** для второго и третьего питонов. Как правило, эти две версии различаются в названии модуля. Либо в описании модуля явно прописано для какой версии питона этот модуль.

Поэтому, вполне возможна ситуация, что Вы установили модуль для двойки и видите его установленным, но при запуске троечной версии он будет недоступен.

Проверьте модули, которые Вы используете, на этом сайте: https://pypi.org/

Comment: Здравствуйте!Спасибо за Ваш ответ!то что библиотеки для 2 и 3 питона разные это я уже понял(проверял командами "pip list" и "pip3 list")

Comment: у меня есть проблема с библиотекой tkinter насколько я это понял,потому что когда я через командную строку ввожу:
python3.6
все ок.он запускает
далее:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
выдает ошибку:
No module named 'tkinter'

Comment: @KirillDotsenko *No module named 'tkinter'* - но если появляется это сообщение, проверьте, а модуль у Вас действительно установлен? Проще всего - посмотрите, есть каталог */usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/* , или нет. Если нет - установите! Я делал установку не через pip3, а стандартным убунтовским установщиком Synaptic. Установил модуль python3-tk. После этого, всё заработало.

Comment: А Вы установили библиотеку *python3-matplotlib* ?

Comment: Здравствуйте!забыл Вам ответить.в итоге проблема была в том что на моей сборке стоял прокси который не давал мне нормально работать при подключении через другую точку доступа.проблема была решена после того как был сделан бридж